# Nested blocks in Dataflow

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Can I, and is it good practice to call Blocks within other Blocks in TPL Dataflow? So if i'm processing an image layer, containing 4 channels (R,G,B,A), the ProcessLayer block feeds all 4 into a ProcessChannel block, and then does something with the output when they're done. Is this kosher or should I be attempting to split the blocks up so that ProcessLayer outputs 4 channels, rather than do the per-channel block posting inside itself?

Context: 
I'm processing a PSD image file using a custom parser, which is a graph of layers->channels. Synchronously, I iterate through each layer, and through each channel. Said PSD's are sometimes 500mb+ in size, and this was taking forever so I decided to try out TPL Dataflow.

Comment: Could you clarify how exactly would `ProcessLayer` work? Because there is no direct way of tracking “when they're done” in TDF. Do you mean that each iteration of `ProcessLayer` would create its own instance of `ProcessChannel`?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow blocks are ideally arranged in a chain with links between them. But when that doesn't work for you, having the body of one block Post messages to 'subsequent' blocks in a pseudo chain is perfectly fine.